# 'type' object is not iterable drf

Tags: postman, authorization, django-authentication

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication) 
   permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
   queryset = ProductInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
   serializer_class = ProductSerializer
   filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
   search_fields = ['title','code','owner__username']
```

[image]

I try to use token authentication for authorizating this class view. and I get an error. plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `authentication_classes` as an iterable, so you need to add the `,`:

```
   authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
```

or just define it as a list:

```
   authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```